# Return a deleted node in binary search tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I am implementing the delete method for a binary search tree that must return the deleted node.

I am having problems returning the deleted node for the case when the deleted node has two children. For deletion of a node with two children, the successor is copied to the deleted node, and I make a recursive call to delete the successor. The successor is returned as the deleted node, and the current call also returns the successor because I made "deleted" an instance variable.

I actually think the bigger issue is that delete shouldn't be an instance variable. I made it an instance variable because my method was required to return something, and for some reason it would always reach the last return statement. That's why I made "deleted" an instance variable. Obviously, having each call overwrite "deleted" isn't the right way to do this, so my "solution" didn't really get me anywhere. Any pointers?

```
// Case 3: internal node, two children
            else {

                BSTNode succ = currRoot.findMin(currRoot, 
                                                currRoot.getRChild());

                // currRoot is a right child
                if (currRoot.getPerson().getKey() >= 
                    parent.getPerson().getKey()) {

                    deleted = new Person(currRoot.getPerson().getName(), 
                                         currRoot.getPerson().getKey());

                    // copying successor to current node
                    currRoot.getPerson().
                             setKey(succ.getPerson().getKey());
                    currRoot.getPerson().
                             setName(succ.getPerson().getName());

                    deleteHelper(currRoot, currRoot.getRChild(), 
                                 succ.getPerson().getKey(), 
                                 succ.getPerson().getName());

                    return deleted;
                }

                // currRoot is a left child
                else {
                    deleted = new Person(currRoot.getPerson().getName(), 
                                         currRoot.getPerson().getKey());

                    // copying successor to current node
                    currRoot.getPerson().setKey(succ.getPerson().getKey());
                    currRoot.getPerson().setName(succ.getPerson().
                                                 getName());

                    deleteHelper(currRoot, currRoot.getRChild(), 
                                 succ.getPerson().getKey(), 
                                 succ.getPerson().getName());

                    return deleted;
                } 
            }
  return deleted; // I don't know why my code reaches here, but I know this is 
                  // what the last recursive call is returning. That's why
                  // I made deleted an instance variable
```

Comment: You might want to post the entire class, or it's hard to see how the recursion is done. In general, you want to keep the internal state and return values of a recursion within its own scope, i.e. as local variables instead of instance variables.